# SQL ORA-00936 missing expression error, where is the missing expression?

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00936

Here is the SQL I wrote:

```
SELECT j.ticketid
     , j.description AS "JU_DESCRIPTION"
     , j.pgejutype
     , j.status AS "JU_STATUS"
     , w.wonum
     , w.description AS "WO_DESCRIPTION"
     , w.jpnum
     , w.status AS "WO_STATUS"
     , w.actfinish,
FROM maximo.workorder w
LEFT OUTER JOIN maximo.relatedrecord r ON r.recordkey = w.wonum AND r.class = 'WORKORDER' AND r.siteid = w.siteid
LEFT OUTER JOIN maximo.sr j ON r.relatedreckey = j.ticketid
WHERE j.jpnum = 'JUINSP'
AND w.istask = 0;
```

Error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

What is missing?  Thank you!

Comment: Remove comma before the `from` clause, after the field name  `, w.actfinish,`  => `, w.actfinish`.

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT j.ticketid
         , j.description AS "JU_DESCRIPTION"
         , j.pgejutype
         , j.status AS "JU_STATUS"
         , w.wonum
         , w.description AS "WO_DESCRIPTION"
         , w.jpnum
         , w.status AS "WO_STATUS"
         , w.actfinish
```

**(remove the "," here)**

```
FROM maximo.workorder w
LEFT OUTER JOIN maximo.relatedrecord r ON r.recordkey = w.wonum AND r.class = 'WORKORDER' AND r.siteid = w.siteid
LEFT OUTER JOIN maximo.sr j ON r.relatedreckey = j.ticketid
WHERE j.jpnum = 'JUINSP'
AND w.istask = 0;
```